Example of Grauert's Division Theorem
We are trying to compute an explicit example of Grauert's Division Theorem, as it appears in De Jong and Pfister's Local Analytic Geometry book.
In particular we are trying to compute the following example (Remark 7.2.2 in said book): we want the normal form of the polynomial $f(x,y) = x^2y+xy^2+y^2$ with respect to the polynomials $f_1(x,y)=y^2-1$ and $f_2(x,y)=xy$, and using the degree lexicographical order with weights $(1,1)$. We have reached a dead point, if anyone could check where we went wrong we'd be really grateful.
Just in case: this order means that $x^ay^b < x^cy^d$ if and only if $a+b < c+d$ or if $a+b=c+d$, then it follows the normal lexicographical order.
We have tried following the argument in Grauert's Division Theorem proof (Theorem 7.1.9). Since we are working with polynomials, we have no convergence problems. The argument is as follows: define the $\mathbb N^2$-semimodule:
$$\Delta = \langle (a,b),(c,d)\rangle $$
where $x^ay^b$ is the leading monomial of $f_1$ and $x^cy^d$ is the leading monomial of $f_2$. In this case:
$$\Delta = \langle (0,0),(1,1)\rangle = \mathbb N^2$$
Now define:
$$\Delta_1 = \langle(0,0)\rangle = \mathbb N^2$$
$$\Delta_2 = \langle(1,1)\rangle \cap (\Delta - \langle(0,0)\rangle) = \emptyset$$
Secondly, define for each $g = \sum_{(a,b)\in\mathbb N^2} g_{(a,b)}x^ay^b$:
$$r(g) = \sum_{(a,b)\not\in\Delta} g_{(a,b)} x^ay^b$$
$$q_i(g) = \frac{1}{x^{\alpha_i}y^{\beta_i}}\sum_{(a,b)\in\Delta_i} g_{(a,b)} x^ay^b$$
for $i = 1,2$, where $(\alpha_1,\beta_1)=(0,0)$ and $(\alpha_2,\beta_2) =(1,1)$
In our case, this means that for every $g$, $r(g) = 0$ and $q_2(g) = 0$. Then the proof says to construct recursively:
$$v_0 = f$$
$$v_{j+1} = v_j - (q_1(v_j)f_1 + q_2(v_j)f_2 +r(v_j))$$
And then, setting $v = \sum_{j=0}^\infty v_j$ the normal form decomposition would be:
$$f = q_1(v)f_1+q_2(v)f_2+r(v)$$
where the desired normal form would be $r(v)$. However, Remark 7.2.2 says that $r(v)$ should be equal to $x+1$, yet in our case $r(v) = 0$ regardless of $v$. It seems we have made a mistake computing the semimodules $\Delta, \Delta_1,\Delta_2$, but we do not see where the mistake is. Could anyone help us please?

The leading monomial of $f_1$ is $y^2$ which has exponent vector $(0,2)$.

Could you explain why the $-1$ is not the leading term? In the book, the leading monomial is defined as the minimal monomial of $f_1$ with non-zero coefficient. If i am not mistaken, $1$ is the minimal monomial in the degree lexicographical ordering.

Note: I have edited the definition of the $q_i$ since it was missing a term, but the problem persists.

Note 2: I tried re-doing the computations  @RicardoBuring said and everything works out, but i still do not understand why $1$ is not the leading monomial of $f_1$

To be honest I was writing my comment assuming the classical definition for polynomials. I'm not really familiar with the power series setting. The book has a different definition of degree lexicographic order for $\mathbb{C}{x}^N$ than for $\mathbb{C}{x}$, which should be the source of your mistake (see e.g. Definition 7.1.4 and Exercise 7.1.11). If you agree, I can post it as an answer.

If you could explain this better (the fact that i should ignore constants when computing the leading monomial) i will be glad to accept the answer (i think for polynomial orderings $1$ is also minimal). As for the differences of $\mathbb C\lbrace x\rbrace$  and $\mathbb C\lbrace x\rbrace^N$, i think since $N=1$ it is the same ordering as in $\mathbb C\lbrace x\rbrace$
